# Create a physical copy of a source file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, if I try to copy a file from one project to another (by using Copy and Paste or by dragging the file to the new project while holding the Ctrl key) it creates a reference to the source file in the original location. Is there a way to create a physical copy of the source file and place that in the target project source direction without having to resort to using Windows Explorer to copy the file manually?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fb6xxhb.aspx Basically, if you want to have full control, you have to resort to Windows explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but when I want to do what you're suggesting, I double-click on the file in Visual Studio, which opens it. Then I do a `File->Save As`, choose the right directory and save it. All from within Visual Studio. This is usually followed by adding the new file to the other project.

Was just doing this and realized I should mention a side-effect. Depending on your source control (in my case, TFS 2010), doing this from within Visual Studio may modify the location of the file in the project. For me, this means making sure that neither the file nor its project have any pending changes, doing the save as, then doing an undo of the change this causes in TFS 2010 (project change, file add and delete).

Comment: Not thought of that. I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fb6xxhb.aspx:

> If you are working with solution items, Visual C++ projects, or other similar projects, you are always working with links in Solution Explorer. If you are working with Visual Basic projects, Visual C# projects, and other projects, you might be working with links or files.

Essentially, the answer to my question is 'No'. In most cases, I must use Windows Explorer.

Comment: Is this question specific to Visual C++ projects? If so, you should note that in the question/title and tag the question accordingly.